# how to create crt and .ovpn files in openvpn

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am using a script which basically copy below files at `/etc/openvpn/` location. A teammate created this files in our team, now left the company. Could someone please help me to understand How can I create this files.

```
ca.crt
dh2048.pem
openvpn.crt
openvpn.key
```

This is part of my server.conf.

```
ca   ca.crt
dh   dh2048.pem
cert openvpn.crt
key  openvpn.key

auth   SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC

script-security       2
```

I am really having hard time understanding client side crt and server side crt. I think above is server side. Also, the one main issue How will I create .ovpn file out of this.

If someone can provide me any documentation on to understand more better that would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you're asking about are the components of an openssl chain of trust.

The ca.crt is a public certificate generated from a keyfile (likely called ca.key) using openssl.

The openvpn.key file was generated using openssl (likely with openvpn's easy-rsa scripts) and used  (again likely by openssl via the easy-rsa scripts) to generate the openvn.crt file.

The openvpn.cert file is the certificate that openvpn offers up to clients that are attempting to negotiate a connection.

The dh2048.pem contains the diffie Hellman parameters the server will offer up for encrypted connections - it's also generated with openssl, likely by way of the way easy-rsa scripts.

Here's a [good walkthrough](https://openmaniak.com/openvpn_pki.php) that explains the Private Key Infrastructure common to most open source openvpn implementations - it should provide an operational understanding of all these files.

If you need a more general theoretical understanding of openssl based PKI,  checkout this [tutorial](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest)